# Best way to deal with polymer element inheritance

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, web-component

Given an element like:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            #container {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="container" on-click="{{clickContainer}}">
            ... lots of other stuff here ...
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('custom-element', {
            clickContainer: function() {

            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I'd like to have another element that wraps the first:

```
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element" extends="custom-element">
    <!-- extra styling -->
    <script>
        Polymer('my-custom-element', {
            clickContainer: function() {
                this.super();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

My problems:

- What's the best way to specify additional styling ?
- Can I wrap the base element in additional markup (like another container) ?
- Can I select elements from the base element ? Something like `<content select=".stuff">` but for the base's shadow markup.

Comment: These are good questions. I don't have answers for you yet but we are working on it. Specifically, we are dancing with the platform/spec teams about disposition of style resolution in sibling shadow-roots. I hope to have some answers for you soon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> - What's the best way to specify additional styling ?

1. Put a template inside the subclass (`my-custom-element`), as usual.
2. Include a `<shadow></shadow>` element where you want the superclass template to appear.
3. Put a style tag into the new template.
4. To style elements that come from the superclass template, use a selector like this:

`:host::shadow .someclass { ... }`

See example below.

> - Can I wrap the base element in additional markup (like another container) ?

Yes, you can put whatever markup you want around the `<shadow></shadow>`.

```
<div>
  <shadow></shadow>
</div>
```

> - Can I select elements from the base element? Something like `<content select=".stuff">` but for the base's shadow markup.

No. You cannot project like that (it's the *reverse direction* from all other projections).

If you really want to cherry-pick nodes out of the older shadow-root, this can be done in code by pulling nodes directly out of `this.shadowRoot.olderShadowRoot`. But this can be tricky because the superclass may have expectations about the structure.

Example code:

```
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element" extends="custom-element">
<template>

  <style>
      /* note that :host::shadow rules apply 
         to all shadow-roots in this element,
         including this one */
      :host::shadow #container { 
        color: blue;
      }
      :host {
        /* older shadow-roots can inherit inheritable 
           styles like font-family */
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
  </style>
  <p>
    <shadow></shadow>
  </p>

</template>
<script>

  Polymer('my-custom-element', {
    clickContainer: function() {
      this.super();
    }
  });

</script>
</polymer-element>
```

ProTips:

- `olderShadowRoot` will exist whether or not you include the `<shadow></shadow>` tag, but it will not be part of the rendered DOM unless you do.
- to prevent `olderShadowRoot(s)` from being created you can override `parseDeclarations` ([source](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/blob/master/src/instance/base.js#L135)). Any of `parseDeclarations`, `parseDeclaration`, `fetchTemplate` can be overidden for various effects.

Comment: Can you explain the example in #4 (and why you need that specific selector). Are there any alternative ways to style ?

Comment: Today, the native behavior is to scope styles in a shadow-root to that specific shadow-root. However, the `:host::shadow` selector refers to _all_ shadow-roots in the current host, including inherited shadow-roots. It's a blunt tool, but it allows `:host::shadow .foo` to style anything with `foo` class in all shadow-roots of the current host. You can also do styling via `\deep\\` combinator, but this is also blunt. We are pushing on the specs, as well as experimenting with meta-systems for improving ergonomics here, see [core-style](https://github.com/polymer/core-style).

Comment: Why do you need to have the `<script>` *inside* the `<polymer-element>` ? Eg: here it's outside: https://github.com/geelen/x-gif/blob/gh-pages/src/x-gif.html

What's going on ? Why did they put it outside ?

Comment: You can put the script anywhere you want. However, in an import, if you put the script inside the `<polymer-element>` you can omit the element name when calling `Polymer()` (i.e. you can just call `Polymer({ ... });`).

Comment: How come all the examples don't do this? Doesn't seem to be documented either (or I haven't looked properly).

Comment: Also, how to deal with internals ? - eg, you want "protected" methods - they shouldn't be accessible through the element but be available internally and for elements that extend

Comment: Examples tend to include the script inside the element because it's generally convenient. The don't often omit the name to `Polymer()` because there are caveats one has to explain. This is the same reason it's poorly documented at the moment, because there is concern people will become confused if they do it in the main document (like a JSbin) and it doesn't work. There is no such concept as `protected` in JavaScript. Use closures, or _ convention.

Comment: Any easy way to get bidirectional binding if I want to store my data and private functions in closures ?

Comment: SO is going to complain that we have too many comments, suggest you make a new question about how to use private data in Polymer instances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57870/discussion-between-ionelmc-and-scott-miles).